# PayPal ExpressCheckout API : Get transaction total in local currency

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

Is there a way of getting the total for the transaction (or better yet, split between shipping, subtotal etc.) in merchant's local currency using the ExpressCheckout API - even though the transaction has been done using different currency code?

Example would be someone who has selected USD on the website to display prices in and paid using USD when redirected to PayPal, but the business (merchange) who receives the funds is based in UK and his default currency is GBP.

Is there a way to get the sub-totals in GBP using ExpressCheckout API? I couldn't find anything within the GetExpressCheckoutDetails and DoExpressCheckoutPayment calls - so not quite sure it's possible at all.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  I see you're posting some questions and seemingly answering them yourself...I'm guessing to build sort of a knowledge base of information on here.  

You didn't answer this one, though, so are you leaving it open for answers or did you just not get to the answer yet..??

Comment: Sorry Andrew - not sure what you mean - I only answer the question myself when I figure it out and no-one else answers it - and that certainly didn't happen that often?

Comment: Sorry, I saw PayPal_Robert and thought he had submitted the question.  I guess he just updated it, so nevermind my comment.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, GetExpressCheckoutDetails will not allow you to return specific currencies, but you could use the [ConvertCurrency API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/ConvertCurrency_API_Operation/) to convert the value returned by GECD to what you need.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Angell - that however will not give me the precise result if for any reason in the meantime the currency exchange rate has changed and since it's for the accounting purposes, I need to be sure that I have precise amount that has been credited to my PayPal account - although it doesn't look like the ExpressCheckout API has this sort of functionality built in.